# Error checking behavior of makefile

Tags: makefile, return-value

If my program has to return different values (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, etc) for different outcomes (mostly errors), the makefile that calls this program would have to stop executing the rest of the makefile commands. Is there a way to continue executing the makefile even if that command produced an error (return a non-zero value)?

Thank you all.

Comment: Did you try `-k` or `--keep-going` option provided by `make`?

Comment: @another.anon.coward It works now, simply by adding a "-" in front of the execution line. Thanks though.

Comment: Maybe you can post that as answer & accept the same. It might be useful to someone in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mycommand; test $? -gt 3
```

Change the test as appropriate. I don't think using `-` or `-k` is a good idea, as it will stop `make` from detecting errors.

Note the 2 commands MUST be on the same line, when in a makefile.

*Added after comment feedback:*
You can also do the following, to allow you to unconditionally run follow-on commands before reacting to an error:

```
mycommand; status=$PIPESTATUS; follow-on-command && test $status -gt 3
```

Comment: I guess the error is still detected as I also display the error message on the console. I just need the rest of the commands to run instead of break from that line. thanks though.

Comment: The error is not detected by make; The error message will come from mycommand, but sh (that runs the line of commands) will return the resultant error code (that of the last semicolon separated command).

Answer (score 3):

To test a command that I know will return a non-zero exit code, I use like this:

```
test: mybadcommand
    mybadcommand; test $$? -eq 1
```

This tests that mybadcommand returns a 1 exit value.  Note that in Makefiles, you are **required** to escape the shell variable which refers to exit statuses, because in the world of make $? means dependencies that are newer than the target.

Thus, in the above snippet, be careful to use **$$?** rather than $?.