# determining whether javadoc encountered any errors or warnings

Tags: java, javadoc

I would like to determine whether the javadoc command that we issue from a makefile encounters any errors or warnings. Currently, I can see that we're encountering errors due to import statements that are not on the classpath that we specify to javadoc (but should be). I ultimately want to fix our javadoc invocation and content and then lock it down so that any error or warning will be caught by the makefile and stop the build. However, as far as I can tell, the documentation does not mention any return code values from the javadoc command. Note that we're using Java 7 and running javadoc from a command in a GNU makefile, not from Ant or Maven. What do you recommend that I do?

UPDATE: My command looks like this:

```
<path1>/javadoc -overview <path2>/overview.html -sourcepath <path3> <file1> <file2> <dir1> <dir2> -d <output_dir>
```

There's nothing I can see in that call that would cause errors to be treated as warnings.

Here's a fragment from the output that shows the error/warning messages I'm seeing:

```
....
Constructing Javadoc information...
../../../<path>/<filename>.java:5: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent;
....
```

The word "error" appears in them, but at the end, the output says only "50 warnings". If I add another issue (such as the `@invalid` tag suggested in one of the answers), I get 51 warnings.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though javadoc 1.7 reports errors, it returns with a zero return value, so the build doesn't catch it. However, javadoc 1.8 returns with a nonzero return value, which the build does catch.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried from the commandline, when no errors are present, a value of zero is returned:

```
> javadoc my.package.name
> ....
> echo $?
> 0
```

After editing a javadoc command with:

```
/**
 * @invalid
 */
```

and running the same javadoc command again, I get an error message and a return code of 1:

```
> javadoc my.package.name
> ....
> ./my/package/name/Coordinate.java:21: error: unknown tag: invalid
> * @invalid
>   ^
> ....
> echo $?
> 1
```

So you just should check if the return value of `javadoc` is 0 or not. If you do not know how to check that return, read [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105577)

Comment: In my case, the `javadoc` command returns 0 when run from the command line even if I receive messages that contain the text "error". At the end, those are all counted as warnings. If I add an `@invalid` call, it just increments the number of warnings. I updated my original question to indicate that.

Comment: @Alan: what is this `<path1>`syntax? That does not look like GNU Makefile syntax to me. And where are you checking the return value of the javadoc command?

Comment: <path1> is my shorthand for "a path that I don't want to write out in full".

Comment: In the original makefile, the javadoc command is issued from a makefile. If the return value were nonzero, the build would terminate with an error, but instead, the build is terminating successfully. I copied the resulting command to the command line and executed it so I could verify that it is returning 0, and it is. My current question is "Why does javadoc report errors, but return successfully?"